# How to get Python tkinter application to run automatically (and reliably) at RPi startup?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, raspberry-pi

I would like to run a Python tkinter application on a Raspberry PI (4b) at startup without the need to manually run the script once the device is turned on.

The target experience is to plug in the device and have it directly boot into the Python tkinter GUI.

There are a lot of questions and answers out there for how to run a Python program at RPi boot, however, there are some common issues that prevent it from working consistently with a GUI application. I have spent a lot of time testing the best way to do this an wanted to share the best approach I found. See below for details!

Answer (score 0):

## Common (Bad) Approaches

First let's go through some common approaches and understand where and why they fail:

1. Running the script via `.bashrc`/`.zshrc`/`.bash_profile`

   - This idea here is to add a line like `python3 script.py` to one of these files so that it gets run when the OS is booted up. Sometimes you will see the suggestion to use a delay (I.e. `sleep 30 && python3 script.py`). This approach is not stable and does not typically work for GUI applications due to the display. During boot, the display takes some time to 'warm up' and is sometimes not available when this code is invoked (note, the screen is unavailable not just unset, meaning even setting `DISPLAY:=0` sometimes will not work). This will end up crashing the tkinter application if it tries to run without the display. The use of `sleep` is to delay the program until the display is available, however, this means that you have a static latency that may not be required in all cases, which is no good.
2. Execution via `crontab`

   - Cron is a tool for executing commands on time intervals or at key events, such as bootup. This is fine for some applications, however, using the cron `@reboot` event you can run into the same issues as before. The display is not always available, and having static latency via `sleep` is not a good workaround.
3. Execution via `systemctl` configuration

   - This is actually the method that we will end up using, however, many tutorials for setting this up will run into the same display issues! It is important to point out that many tutorials say they configure the `systemctl` service to launch on display availability, however, even with using `After=graphical.target` the display may not always be available!!! Below I will go over how we can overcome this.

## Reliable Approach

#### Overview

To reliably launch a tkinter application at boot we will setup a `systemctl` service tied to the `graphical.target` then we will block and wait for the display to become available within our program.

#### Why?

We want to use `systemctl` because it provides an easy way to configure, start, and stop our program. We want to block and detect display availability so that it is able to launch the GUI at the earliest availability. This notion of waiting within the program is the key for reliability.

#### How (step by step)?

1. Run `sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/my-service.service` changing 'my-service' to the name of your choice.
2. Configure the service by pasting the following in (make sure to update the contents with your path and name):

```
[Unit]
Description=My Application
After=graphical.target
Wants=graphical.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=prototype
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
ExecStart=python3 /home/path-to-program/main.py

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

3. Run `sudo systemctl enable my-service.service`
4. Within your code base, setup your tk window as such:

```
def initialize_gui():
   root_window = tk.Tk()
   # Setup GUI, ect.
   root_window.mainloop()

while True:
   try:
      initialize_gui()
   except Exception as e:
      print(f"Waiting for GUI to become available: {e}")
      time.sleep(0.2) # Small delay, not needed but recommended
```

And there you have it, if the display is not available when the service is started at boot, it will retry until it does become available. After implementing this method I have not had any issues with the program launching on bootup. Hope this helps someone else out because it was a pain to try every technique and figure out.

Comment: The time delay loop should probably be replaced with an `after` timer.

Comment: @СергейКох `mainloop` isn't kicked off at the time the exception is thrown, so `after` is not available